# How to construct a symmetric matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have the following

```
Import numpy as np

Mat1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
            [0, 4, 5],
            [0, 0, 6]])
Mat2 = np.transpose(Mat1)
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
        if i == k:
            Mat2[i,k] = 0
Mat = Mat2 + Mat1
print(Mat)
```

But my answer gives me

```
[[0 2 3]
 [2 0 5]
 [3 5 0]]
```

when I should have `1, 4, 6` in the diagonal. Can anyone see why?

Comment: From the documentation: *A view is returned whenever possible.*. So, by setting the diagonal to zero, you are probably modifying both matrices at the same time.

Comment: Create `Mat2` with `Mat2 = np.transpose(Mat1).copy()`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser bit wasteful, don't you think?

Comment: There is a *lot* in that code that I would change.  My comment is a quick fix for the immediate problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions you may want to consider:

As pointed out by @NicoSchertler the problem with your original approach is that the transpose and the original matrix *share their data*, meaning that whenever you modify an element of one of the two, the corresponding element of the other also changes.

Therefore in both your original and your second approach you probably don't want to write to the transpose. Your second approach is good: add matrix and transpose and deal with the diagonal later. But your first nested loop there has actually no effect, so best leave it out.

Further a nested loop is completely unnecessary and wasteful for setting the diagonal. You can have the same effect by

```
for i in range(3):
    Mat[i, i] = a[i]
```

but you can do even better using numpy's advanced indexing which you want to get familiar with sooner or later anyway:

```
idx = np.arange(3)
Mat[idx, idx] = a
```

This is the *vectorized* form of your loop and you should make a habit of avoiding loops whenever possible and find a vectorized solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
Mat1 = np.array([[0, 2, 3],
            [0, 0, 5],
            [0, 0, 0]])
a = np.array([1, 4, 6])
Mat2 = np.transpose(Mat1)
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
        if i == k:
            Mat2[i,k] = 0
Mat = Mat2 + Mat1
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(3):
        if i == k:
            Mat[i,k] = a[i]
print(Mat)
```

Gives the answer:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [2 4 5]
 [3 5 6]]
```

Works for any size like my other 31 dim matrix.